# Repeated Failure Of Windows Update KB3141491 (32 Bit) - Error Code 80070663

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, microsoft-word-2013

The above update, for Windows Office 2013 (32-Bit Edition) has repeatedly failed since the 8th February. All other updates have gone through. Although it is classified as Important can I ignore it, or if I should not how can I fix it?

Comment: This error number translates to the textual error message "This update package could not be opened. Verify that the update package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer update package". You may want to try manually downloading it from Microsoft and installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54738) and install the [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3141491/february-7-2017-update-for-office-2013-kb3141491) on your own by double clicking the `mso2013-kb3141491-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`. Sometimes Microsoft Update has issues to download all files correctly.

Comment: Downloading and installing as suggested (also by @Jeff Zeitlin) worked. There had been an issue with KB3161988 in the same set of updates but it had worked second time around whereas this hne had failed seven times when I decided to seek advice.